# Search for a specified file on my Windows machine using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I have a file **TestProject.dll** and it resides in different locations on my computer like `D:\Folder1\TestProject.dll`, `D:\Test\Info\TestProject.dll` etc.

I want to find all these locations wherever it is located and prepare a **text file** (*SearchResults.txt*) which looks like as shown below:

> D:\Folder1\TestProject.dll
>   D:\Test\Info\TestProject.dll

I want to do this using a batch scripting file. I am new to this scripting.
Please help me here.

Comment: `dir /b /s D:\TestProject.dll > SearchResults.txt` (and get yourself a cup of coffee - this may take a while)

Comment: Thanks @Stephan!! But I am not sure if the file is in C or D folder? In this case I cant give it like D:\TestProject.dll > SearchResults.txt. Can I please have a more generic solution plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dir /s /b` to search in a single drive.
Build a loop around that to check every disk.
put the complete output into a file.

```
(
  for /f %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption^,size^|find ":"') do (
    echo now checking drive %%a...
    dir /b /s %%a\TestProject.dll 
  )
)>SearchResults.txt
```

Note: we don't really need the size here, this is only one of several ways to come around `wmic`'s ugly line endings, that would ruin the rest of the code
`where drivetype=3` means "Harddisks only" (drop it, if you want to search in all drivetypes (Thumbdrives, CD, whatever)

Remember: this will search through your whole file system(s), so it will need some time.

Comment: Awesome @Stephan it is working. Can I restrict the result to be from a specific Subfolder like result should be from D:\Test ???

Comment: yes, of course. Only in `D:\Test`: `dir /b d:\test\TestProject.dll`. In `D:\Test` and it's subfolders: `dir /s /b d:\test\TestProject.dll` (when there is `/s`, think of it like `dir /b d:\test\*\TestProject.dll` (which won't work - just to imagine it)

Comment: Thanks again but the below script is returning the results twice \n @echo off
set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%\ReadDIB_Helper.dll
(
  for /f %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption^,size^|find ":"') do (
    dir /b /s %arg1%\ReadDIB_Helper.dll 
  )
)>SearchResults.txt   can you please tell me what is wrong with the script?

Comment: `dir /b /s %arg1%\ReadDIB_Helper.dll` - you missed the drive letter, so it lists the same `dir` number-of-your-disks times. Use  `dir /b /s %%a\%arg1%\ReadDIB_Helper.dll`